# Including JavaScript in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, interactive

I am trying to create an interactive SVG code with JavaScript, by embedding the JavaScript in the SVG. I don't know if this is the right way to do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
onkeypress="move()">
<script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
    var x;
    var y;
    function move()
    {
        x = new Number(svg.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].getAttribute("cx"));
        y = new Number (svg.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].getAttribute("cy"));
        switch (event.keyCode)
        {
            case 119:
            y--;
            y = y.toString();
            svg.getElementsByTagName("circle").setAttribute("cy",y);
            break;
            case 115:
            y++;
            y = y.toString();
            svg.getElementsByTagName("circle").setAttribute("cy",y);
            break;
            case 97:
            x--;
            x = x.toString();
            svg.getElementsByTagName("circle").setAttribute("cx",x);
            break;
            case 100:
            x++;
            x = x.toString();
            svg.getElementsByTagName("circle").setAttribute("cx",x);
            break;
            default:
        }
    }
    ]]>
</script>
<rect x="0" y="0" height="500" width="500" style="stroke-width:1; stroke:black; fill:white"></rect>
<circle cx="250" cy="250" r="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

It is supposed to have a ball that moves with wasd, but the ball doesn't move. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Here is a working version as I would write it:

```css
svg {
  height: 178px;
  width: 600px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="250" cy="100" r="50" fill="red" />
  <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    var KEY = { w:87, a:65, s:83, d:68 };
    var moveSpeed = 5;
    var circle = document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0];
    var x = circle.getAttribute('cx')*1,
        y = circle.getAttribute('cy')*1;
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('keydown',function(evt){
      switch (evt.keyCode){
        case KEY.w:
          circle.setAttribute('cy',y-=moveSpeed);
          // Alternatively:
          // circle.cy.baseVal.value = (y-=moveSpeed);
        break;
        case KEY.s:
          circle.setAttribute('cy',y+=moveSpeed);
        break;
        case KEY.a:
          circle.setAttribute('cx',x-=moveSpeed);
        break;
        case KEY.d:
          circle.setAttribute('cx',x+=moveSpeed);
        break;
      }
    },false);
  ]]></script>
</svg>
```

Some notes:

1. Don't re-get the reference to the circle again and again. Making your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) makes it more robust, less typing, and (in this case) faster to execute.

**Edit**: If you cannot figure out how to do this given my code above, post any code that is not working for you.

2. Don't rely on a global `event` object; that's old IE nonsense. Use the event object passed to your event handler.

**Edit**: If you reference `event` in your code with no parameter or local variable by that name, you are assuming that there will be a global `event` object set. Instead, see the code I wrote for you, which shows that the event handler is passed an `event` object. By giving that a name, such as I gave it the name `evt`, you are receiving an event object specific to your event handler.

3. Since you are modifying the `x` and `y` variables, there's no need to re-get the `cx` and `cy` attributes each key press.

**Edit**: In your original code and the answer you accepted, you have declared `var x` outside your event handler, and you have `x = ...` at the start of your event handler, and then `x++` in one of the event handlers. You can either re-get the current value of `x` each time (as you did) and then `setAttribute(...,x+1)`, or (as I did) you can only fetch the value of the attribute *once* before the event handlers and then assume that this value is correct each time you handle the key event.

4. Don't put your JavaScript event handlers on your elements, attach them programmatically.

**Edit**: In your SVG markup you have: `<svg ... onkeypress="move()">`. Mixing your behavior with your markup is a really bad idea in HTML, and a bad idea in SVG. Instead of using `onfoo="..."` attributes to describe what should happen when an event occurs on an element, instead use `addEventListner()` to attach the event handlers via code, without editing your SVG markup.

5. There's no need to coerce the numbers to strings before setting them as attributes.
6. Use `keydown` and the ASCII event codes I supplied above instead of `keypress` and the odd numbers you were using if you want it to work in all browsers.

**Edit**: You complained in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448994/more-svg-questions-and-javascript-interactivity) that you cannot do this because you want the event handler to be processed repeatedly as the key is held down. Note that your desired behavior is achieved with my sample code in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and IE (I don't have Opera to test). In other words `keydown` works as you wanted, despite how you thought it should behave.

**Edit 2**: If you want to include a script block at the top of your document, before all elements have necessarily been created, you can do something like the following:

```
<svg ...>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load',function(){
      var circle = ...;
      document.rootElement.addEventListener('keydown',function(evt){
        ...
      },false);
    },false);
  </script>
  ...
</svg>
```

The outer function will only run once the page has loaded, so you can be sure that the elements exist to reference them.

Comment: I'd suggest using the SVG DOM methods to set cx and cy, but this looks like a good solution apart from that minor thing.

Comment: @Erik Can you provide more details on why you suggest that? Whether using `circle.setAttribute('cy',y)` or `circle.cy.baseVal.value=y` I get 250fps in Chrome and 100fps in FF3.6. Is one or the other faster in your mind? Are you considering some interaction with SMIL?

Answer (score 2):

you can add script js into svg code by declare script tag into svg tag:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
     ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('load',function(){
        alert('Hi')
        })
    </script>   

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Chrome. You had a few errors, like indexing getElementsByTagName only sometimes. Plus the big problem was that the onkeypress attribute wasn't binding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[

    var x;
    var y;
    function move()
    {
        x = new Number(document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].getAttribute("cx"));
        y = new Number (document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].getAttribute("cy"));
        switch (event.keyCode)
        {
            case 119:
            y--;
            y = y.toString();
            document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].setAttribute("cy",y);
            break;
            case 115:
            y++;
            y = y.toString();
            document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].setAttribute("cy",y);
            break;
            case 97:
            x--;
            x = x.toString();
            document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].setAttribute("cx",x);
            break;
            case 100:
            x++;
            x = x.toString();
            document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].setAttribute("cx",x);
            break;
            default:
        }
    }
    document.documentElement.addEventListener("keypress", move);
    ]]>
</script>
<rect x="0" y="0" height="500" width="500" style="stroke-width:1; stroke:black; fill:white"></rect>
<circle cx="250" cy="250" r="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Note that Firefox will cry unless you add the third argument to `addEventListener` explicitly. It's picky that way.

Comment: @mortalc This answer does not work in Firefox, while mine does. It also continues to use code from your answer that is unnecessary and unadvisable.

Comment: I'd never heard of addEventListener before! THAT's why it didn't work!

Comment: @mortalc No offense intended, but there were multiple reasons beyond that one that your code didn't work.

Comment: I can't disagree with that because I don't know better, but I'm just saying that the other one works for me. Just two things that puzzle me. 1) if I set a variable circle to document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0] like you did in yours and use that instead of getting the element each time, it doesn't work. And 2) if I use the code with a rectangle, and replace cx and cy with x and y, it doesn't work. But for some strange reason it does if I get cx and cy but edit x and y.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Example**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<path d="M90,18c-90-45-115,102,0,69v-21l4-3h-23l-8,4h16v19c-80,15-65-106,2-63l-4,5l4-1z" fill="#CCC" stroke="#DDD" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path d="M87,15c-90-45-115,102,0,69v-21l4-3h-23l-8,4h16v19c-80,15-65-106,2-63l-4,5l4-1z" fill="#00F"/>
<script>
    alert("Hello world");
</script>
</svg>
```