# SVG Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to make one of my SVG text fields accept input from the user when they press on it. Is there any way of doing that?

```js
    const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    const text = document.getElementById('Username');
    
    const inputWrapper = document.getElementById('input-wrapper');
    const input = document.getElementById('input');
    const button = document.getElementById('button');
    
    
    text.addEventListener('click', () => {
      text.classList.toggle('hide');
      inputWrapper.classList.toggle('hide');
      input.focus();
    });
    
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      text.classList.toggle('hide');
      inputWrapper.classList.toggle('hide');
    });
    
    input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      text.innerText = e.target.value;
    });
```

```css
         .cls-1 {
            clip-path: url(#clip-Login_page);
          }
    
          .cls-2 {
            opacity: 0.67;
            fill: url(#pattern);
          }
    
          .cls-3 {
            fill: #d9d9d9;
          }
    
          .cls-3, .cls-5 {
            stroke: #0d0d0d;
          }
    
          .cls-4 {
            fill: url(#pattern-2);
          }
    
          .cls-5 {
            fill: #f2f2f2;
          }
    
          .cls-6, .cls-7 {
            fill: #707070;
            font-family: Georgia;
          }
    
          .cls-6 {
            font-size: 25px;
          }
    
          .cls-7 {
            font-size: 20px;
          }
    
          .cls-8 {
            stroke: none;
          }
    
          .cls-9 {
            fill: none;
          }
    
          .cls-10 {
            fill: #fff;
          }
    
          .cls-11 {
            filter: url(#Rectangle_5);
          }
    
          .cls-12 {
            filter: url(#Amcan_logo);
          }
    
          .cls-13 {
            filter: url(#Rectangle_2);
          }
       .hide {
      display: none;
      }
```

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 375 667">
      <defs>
 
        <pattern id="pattern" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
          <image width="1920" height="1080" xlink:href="img/Amcan.gif"/>
        </pattern>
        <filter id="Rectangle_2" x="11" y="178" width="354" height="63" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <feOffset dy="5" input="SourceAlpha"/>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
          <feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/>
          <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>
          <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </filter>
        <pattern id="pattern-2" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 593 186">
          <image width="593" height="186" xlink:href="img/Amcan_logo.png"/>
        </pattern>
        <filter id="Amcan_logo" x="13" y="28" width="349" height="123" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <feOffset dy="10" input="SourceAlpha"/>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur-2"/>
          <feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/>
          <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur-2"/>
          <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </filter>
        <filter id="Rectangle_5" x="77" y="369" width="222" height="63" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <feOffset dy="5" input="SourceAlpha"/>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur-3"/>
          <feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/>
          <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur-3"/>
          <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </filter>
        <clipPath id="clip-Login_page">
          <rect width="375" height="667"/>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      
      <g id="Login_page" data-name="Login page" class="cls-1">
        <rect class="cls-10" width="375" height="667"/>
        <rect id="Amcanerino" class="cls-2" width="510" height="667" transform="translate(-71)"/>
        <g class="cls-13" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)">
          <g id="Rectangle_2-2" data-name="Rectangle 2" class="cls-3" transform="translate(20 182)">
            <rect class="cls-8" width="336" height="45"/>
            <rect class="cls-9" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="335" height="44"/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g class="cls-12" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)">
          <rect id="Amcan_logo-2" data-name="Amcan_logo" class="cls-4" width="331" height="104" transform="translate(22 28)"/>
        </g>
        <g id="Rectangle_3" data-name="Rectangle 3" class="cls-5" transform="translate(20 250)">
          <rect class="cls-8" width="336" height="45"/>
          <rect class="cls-9" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="335" height="44"/>
        </g>
        <g id="Rectangle_4" data-name="Rectangle 4" class="cls-5" transform="translate(20 311)">
          <rect class="cls-8" width="336" height="45"/>
          <rect class="cls-9" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="335" height="44"/>
        </g>
        <g class="cls-11" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)">
          <g id="Rectangle_5-2" data-name="Rectangle 5" class="cls-3" transform="translate(86 373)">
            <rect class="cls-8" width="204" height="45"/>
            <rect class="cls-9" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="203" height="44"/>
          </g>
        </g>
        <text id="SUBMIT" class="cls-6" transform="translate(139 405)"><tspan x="0" y="0">SUBMIT</tspan></text>
     <text id="Login" class="cls-6" transform="translate(156 214)"><tspan x="0" y="0">Login</tspan></text>
     
     <div id="wrapper">
      <text id="Username" class="cls-7" transform="translate(142 280)"><tspan x="0" y="0">Username</tspan></text>
      <div id="input-wrapper" class="hide">
        <input id="input" type="text" value="Username"/>
        <button id="button">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
        <text id="Password" class="cls-7" transform="translate(145 341)"><tspan x="0" y="0">Password</tspan></text>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

This is the amended code as suggested by Solo.

Comment: It's quite tricky. In order to be able to edit svg text you have to put the svg inside a contenteditable element. However you need a way to protect the rest of the content inside the svg from being deleted. This is a pen where the text inside the SVG is editable: [SVG contenteditable Skills](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/PEmQpa) Also: you have `<div>`s inside your svg but you are not using `<foreignObject>` This is not valid code

Answer (score 1):

[`<tspan>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan) and `<text>` are not html elements, but svg elements with their own attributes. The property contenteditable doesn't exist on tspan (you can console.log `document.querySelector("#myTspan").isContentEditable`, it will return `undefined`.

However, it can inherit properties from its parents. So in case of an inline svg in a HTML file, wrapping your svg in an editable element will work in some browsers, but all you texts are then editable.

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
<svg>
<text id="Username" class="cls-7" transform="translate(142 20)"><tspan x="0" y="0">Username</tspan></text>
</svg>
</div>
```

In a standalone SVG, you have no way to have contenteditable working since it's part of HTML specification, not that of SVG.

You have to go for a script as other answers suggest, but read carefully (since you didn't mentionned at first that it was a standalone svg) : [Including JavaScript in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378559/including-javascript-in-svg)

Comment: Text 'Username' has now disappeared, however I'm still not able to add any text in its place :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no, you can't edit the text directly, but you can put an input overtop of it. See the code below:

```css
.input-real {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none transparent;
  line-height: 0;
}

.input-real:focus {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: #333;
}

.input-real,
.input-mimic {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 375 667">
  <text id="Username" class="input-mimic" x="50" y="50" alignment-baseline="hanging">Username</text>
  <foreignObject width="50" height="23" x="50" y="46">
    <input id="input" class="input-real" type="text" value="Username"/>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `contenteditable` on `tspan`

see more here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

> How does it work?
>
> All you have to do is set the contenteditable attribute on nearly any HTML element to make it editable.

```js
function toggleEdit() {
  var text = document.getElementById('Username');
  var tspan = text.firstElementChild;
  tspan.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
}
```

```html
<text id="Username" class="cls-7" transform="translate(142 280)"><tspan x="0" y="0">Username</tspan></text>
<div><button onclick="toggleEdit();">Edit input</button></div>
```

Comment: I think it is meant for HTML's <div> only, it does not seem to work when I change the code :(

Comment: @DanielKlas https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content#How_does_it_work

Comment: How does relate to editable SVG elements as the OP asked?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help guys! I have found out that I can just use JavaScript 'prompt' form to achieve this. All I had to do was to implement the following:

```js
<script>
 function changeUsername()
 {
  document.getElementById('Username').textContent = prompt("Please enter your Username");
 }
 </script>
```

```html
<rect onclick="changeUsername()" class="cls-8" width="336" height="45"/>
```

I completely forgot that the prompt form existed! Again, thank you all :)

Answer (score -1):

No need of jquery or JS,
Just add `contenteditable="true"` to that text element and you're done...

```html
<text contenteditable="true" id="Username" class="cls-7" transform="translate(142 280)"><tspan x="0" y="0">Username</tspan></text>
```

Comment: It doesn't allow me to change the text.

Comment: Yes, the snippet on this site is working perfectly, but when I add it to my document it simply does nothing