# Failures in parameterizing SVG images

Tags: image, svg, parameters

I am trying to create a list of simple images and would like to use vectors.

I have created a simple svg and read the [w3c primer on parameters](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/). As far as I can see, this is a draft. Right now My project is PHP based, but it may not be in the future. Therefore moving to GD is not feasible.

I tried

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="belt.svg">
   <param name="border" value="green" />
   <param name="color" value="white" />
</object>
```

AND

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="belt.svg?color=red"></object>
```

With no success. Any object I try to parameterize turns up invisible. And if I open it in Inkscape, the part of the image is not visible.

My secondary option is treating the svg as a template, and filling in the colours with a server side script, but I would like to avoid that.

## The SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="10mm"
   height="18.531443mm"
   viewBox="0 0 10 18.531443"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   sodipodi:docname="belt.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)">
  <defs
     id="defs2" >
       <ref id="paramBorder" param="border" default="black"/>
       <ref id="paramFill" param="color" default="green"/>
       <ref id="paramSnips" param="snips" default="white"/>
     </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="4"
     inkscape:cx="-105.07289"
     inkscape:cy="88.745915"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="true"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1012"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid3713"
       originx="0"
       originy="-280" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,1.531443)">
    <path
       style="stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26386964px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       fill="url(#paramBorder)"
       d="M 10,17 H 0 V -1.25625 h 10 z"
       id="beltBackground"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.25726196px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       fill="url(#paramBorder)"
       d="M 0,-1.531443 H 10 V 17 H 9.7500003 V -1.2667081 H 0.24999999 V 17 H 0 Z"
       id="beltBorder"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </g>
   <script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" type="text/ecmascript" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="ref.js"/>

</svg>
```

### EDIT #1

I had overseen the [script that had to be included](http://www.schepers.cc/w3c/svg/params/ref.js). In the svg.

Referencing it with `<script src="refs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` as the last element in my `<svg>` did not work. I ended up having to include it [as demonstrated other places int SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5381905/1725871)

The result: now the border is no longer invisible, but only the default colors are shown.

### EDIT #2

I noted that I had used a [refs.js](http://www.schepers.cc/w3c/svg/params/ref.js) and not [params.js](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/param.js) as suggested in the comments. This caused everything to break. I peaked at the source of the Primer site and realized that my original incluce link was incorrect. it is now `<script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" type="text/ecmascript" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="ref.js"/>` which works beautifully, but still only with the default colors.

### EDIT #3

I tried a different parameter, and now it appears to work (in Chrome, FF, Edge)

Comment: did you use/include the param.js polyfill in the first case?

Comment: I hadn't. I tried that now and inlcuded my findings in the question.

Answer (score 0):

My experiments showed me that it was possible anyway. The [newest version of the parameter library](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/ref/master/ref2.js) is most stable.

Trying to access the refs after the script library had set the values gave new issues. SO i copied a part of the script to access the values and act on them:

```
getNumSnips();
function getNumSnips() {
    var href = document.defaultView.location.href;
    if (-1 != href.indexOf("?")) {
        var paramList = href.split("?")[1].split(/&|;/);
        for (var p = 0, pLen = paramList.length; pLen > p; p++) {
            var eachParam = paramList[p];
            var valList = eachParam.split("=");
            var name = unescape(valList[0]);
            var value = unescape(valList[1]);
            console.log(name + ":" + value);

        }
    }

}
```