# Create a Github badge

Tags: javascript, github, svg, markdown

I want to create a badge for Github README (like [this](https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats) for example). I created a function to get the GET value from URL using JavaScript and put it in the SVG, that works when I tried it in local but if I put it in a Markdown file it doesn't change the number.

`![No](http://luigitest.altervista.org/widget/font.svg?years=9)`

index.svg:

```html
<svg width="200" height="75" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
style="-webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;">
  

<g>  
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="125" height="75" style="fill:#F84949F5"></rect>
  <text x="0" y="37.5" font-family="Segoe UI" font-size="16"  font-weight="bold" fill="white">
    <tspan x="62.5" text-anchor="middle" dy="-3.5%">I started</tspan>
    <tspan x="62.5" text-anchor="middle" dy="25%">programming</tspan>
  </text>
  <rect x="124" y="0" width="75" height="75" style="fill:#F84949"></rect>
  <text x="124" y="75" font-family="Segoe UI" font-size="13" fill="white" font-weight="bold">
    <tspan x="162.5" text-anchor="middle" y="45.891675" font-size="40" id="years-number">5</tspan>
    <tspan x="162.5" text-anchor="middle" y="67.5"  font-weight="bold">years ago</tspan>
  </text>
</g>  
<script xlink:href="script.js" />
</svg>
```

script.js:

```js
function changeNumber() {
    document.getElementById("years-number").textContent = getValue;
}

let getValue;

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    let name="years";
    if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
      getValue = decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
  
    changeNumber();
});
```

Output in the browser:
[correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wnx7.png)

Output in markdown (correct one):
[wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puBVm.png)

How can I fix it?

Comment: github is https, I don't think you can load a remote resource over http://, your get mixed content issues, you may need to add ssl

Comment: try putting the svg inside the svg element like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378559/including-javascript-in-svg

Comment: I tried using a website with SSL but nothing changes @LawrenceCherone

Comment: Not even putting js inside the svg element it works @enxaneta

Comment: getting any errors? *not works* is not really helpful is the SVG even showing?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone When I add markdown code it shows me the svg with the default number (5) without changing it by interting the number inside the GET variable.

Comment: I would imagine that markdown is loading the SVG as an image i.e. via an image, img or as a background-image. Script doesn't run if you do it that way.

Comment: Can you include the markdown you're using?

Comment: yes, all badges for github are SVG loaded as an image but they are dynamic and their content changes, mine is not @RobertLongson

Comment: @programmerRaj I write the code at the begin of the thread: `![No](http://luigitest.altervista.org/widget/font.svg?years=9)`

Comment: script.js is inside index.svg so it will not be executed. The other icons must work differently. Maybe they use SMIL or CSS animations.

Comment: Maybe generate a svg file based on `years` server side?

Comment: @programmerRaj but using this method there will not be any preview

Comment: @Vector what do you mean by 'preview'? Like when you are editing the html file?

Comment: @programmerRaj the "preview" that comes out by using that code markdow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a serverless function using template svg and pupa.

Svg file:

```xml
...svg
    <tspan x="162.5" text-anchor="middle" y="45.891675" font-size="40" id="years-number">{years}</tspan>
...svg
```

Server side code:

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69164294/create-a-github-badge
import pupa from 'pupa'
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
import { join } from 'path'
import { dirname } from 'dirname-filename-esm'

const __dirname = dirname(import.meta)
const template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '../badge.svg'), 'utf8')

export default (req, res) => {
  let { years } = req.query
  if (typeof years !== 'string') return res.status(400).end()
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
  res.end(pupa(template, { years }))
}
```

I used [Vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/serverless-functions/supported-languages#node.js) to deploy the serverless function. There are ways other than Vercel too.

Link to repl: https://replit.com/@Programmerraj/serverless-api#api/index.js

Link to live example: https://serverless-api-ebon.vercel.app/api?years=6 (change `years` to be anything).

Link to GitHub repo: https://github.com/ChocolateLoverRaj/serverless-api.

Preview written in markdown in this answer:
[image: preview]

Comment: I would like to add a second parameter (color) but doing ```let { years } = req.query.years; let color = req.query.color``` (and than do ```const template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '../'+color+'.svg'), 'utf8');``` gives me problems like ```The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared```. I also tried other methods to get the parameters (https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/15963931) and declare the variable 'template' in different ways with an if but it still doesn't work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you need a seperate file for every color? Why not just put the color as part of the template.

Comment: It's a good idea but the error remains